# Kudos to you and its usage

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What does Kudos to you exactly mean?
Can I use it instead of"Bravo"?
I hear it a lot in "Californication".

Comment: Merriam-Webster Online (a general reference as that term is understood at this site) offers a [couple of clear definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kudos) of _kudos_, the second one being the one most people have in mind when they use the word today. As far as I know, there is no reason you couldn't say "Kudos!" in place of "Bravo!" in many instances.

Comment: Just remember to keep the S. There is no such thing as a **kudo**.

Answer (score 5):

"Kudos" is the Greek word for praise, which English has swallowed whole.  (Note that it ends in an "s," but it's no more plural than gyros.)

From the pilot of [*Californication*](http://genius.com/Californication-pilot-annotated):

> HEATHER: You drifted off. And I thought to myself, “Self, what's the
>   nicest possible way I could wake up Mr. Hank here?”
>
> HANK: Well, **kudos** to you, because you definitely stumbled upon one of
>   the nicer ways.

"**kudos** to you":  Let me praise you.

Comment: Interesting that you should bring up _gyros_. When I lived in Washington, D.C., and New York City years ago, a _gyro_ was widely understood to refer to a sandwich-like offering consisting of seasoned, thinly sliced lamb in a pita bread pocket. I've never heard anyone refer to a _kudo_, however. It sounds like a large African antelope.

Comment: @SvenYargs You're thinking of "kudu."  They make an excellent gyro.

Comment: No, no, that's that vine that covers up everything—lambs and antelopes included—that goes near dirt in the Sovereign South.

Comment: @SvenYargs That's "kudzu."  Makes a nice salad.

Comment: Why so it is. Well, enough of this silliness. +1 for providing a perfectly sound answer to the poster's question.

Comment: *Kudos* was used long before *Californication*. You should have written as "For example, From the pilot of *Californication*". Otherwise, you would be giving the impression that  *Californication* originated the usage in English.

Comment: @Sven Yarga: Did you know that _gyros_ describes _how the meat is cooked (on a vertical spit), whether or not it is put on a sandwich_ —just as _k{a/e}b{o/a} b)_ describes meat cooked a particular way, whether it is folded in flatbread, or stuck on a skewer (_shish kabob_).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: I didn't, but it certainly makes sense: the places that sell these sandwiches typically have the spitted (and gyrating) meat on display behind the counter, and many display the word _Gyros_ in large letters outside their shops. I'm sure that the (non-Greek) customers who ask for "a gyro" do so because they mistakenly read _gyros_ as a plural. In any case, the mistake is now pervasive. E.g., Wikipedia has an entry for "[Gyro (food)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyro_%28food%29)" and The Gyro Company has a page called "[What's a Gyro?](http://www.thegyrocompany.com/gyro/)."